# What is the "resource file" when building Unity3D project with WebGL and what needs to be considered using the Unity3D WebGL-Build?

Tags: unity-game-engine, firefox, rendering, webgl

I am trying to build a small project with Unity3D and I want to display it locally in my Firefox-Browser.
In my Unity-Editor it looks like this: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJRgh.png)
And if I am building it as WebGL it looks like this:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0SvD.png)

The Images which are being displayed in the Browser are imported as `.gltf` Objects and the green planes are built within the unity-hub. I assumed that it may be because of the lightning and so I tried including a `PointLight`, but that did not work.

I also tried the same with a new project only containing a cube, but that did not work either as there was as well only a grey screen in the browser, so there is a problem with displaying objects created in the Unity-Hub directly. Inspecting the Website I am getting a lot of Errors which are referencing the resource file [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0s1L.png), as I assume that this is the main source of problems.

I am new to Unity and WebGL and could not find any solutions or even approaches to this problem and was hoping for maybe an explanation what the errors are even about.

workspace:
unity version: 2021.2.1f1
small local webserver with python where I am putting the .html file on
compression disabled in the player settings of the WebGL-Build

Comment: OK, you didnt make it in unity hub, its just a hub to run unity - if it doesnt work in webgl that seems odd considering it doesnt look overly complex but you havent really explained if that is a predone scene eg it looks like that at design time or generated or using dots, or not, or anything..   How can we recreate your problem (Ive made with some missing features cos I havent written them yet) a full 3d rpg underground dungeon in unity and posted it as webgl and its all fine.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I hope Unity-Editor is the right word? The scene is as you mentioned predone containing 2 gltf objects, one capsule and 3 planes. Also I included one C# Script to make the objects clickable, but thats it. Did you run your project locally and did you have to consider for example special lights for the WebGL Build?

Comment: nope, absolutely not.. (https://sillygames.online/DungeonDisasters/index.html its a bit pants but meh it was the first thing i was making) however, running it "locally" you still need a webserver, or for unity to run it (which makes a temp web server) you cant just click on files and hope.

Comment: Step-By-Step I did this for the small test-project with the same errors: create 3D Project =>  include one cube => disable compression (for firefox) => build Scene as WebGL => start python webserver => drag index.html on local python webserver

Comment: I have never used python as a webserver, but, you do need more than just the html file..

Comment: The errors I get are mostly from the "Projectsname.framework.js" so all build-files should be included.  Is it important what kind of a server I am using? Like do I maybe have to use a Game-Server and my python-server is too plain or does it not matter? Sorry for asking maybe rookie-questions, but I am confused and also a rookie

Comment: well any errors mean unlikely to work - what is important about your webserver is you set it up just the way unity need it, which is semi counter intuative IMHO, as they want compressed files but without compressed extensions.. so you should make sure you obey all of that. the fact its complaining it depends what.... and most errors are self explainatory

Comment: I will try looking into that issue with compression and setting up my webserver as unity wants, Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by moving to an older version (2020.3.22f1) of Unity

Comment: Which version did you need to revert to? That will be useful information for future readers with this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).